# Issue with HashMap<String,Marker> in android

Tags: android, dictionary, hashmap, marker, infowindow

I want to keep track of markers on the map. When a particular marker is clicked, I need to display the info regarding to that marker.

I am using one HashMap variable to keep track of the markers added on to the map.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= PropertyStub.size() - 1; i++) {
        final LatLng MeanLatLng = new LatLng(PropertyStub.get(i).Latitude,
                PropertyStub.get(i).Longitude);

        if (!visibleMarkers.containsKey(PropertyStub.get(i).PropertyID)) {
            visibleMarkers
                    .put(PropertyStub.get(i).PropertyID,
                            this.map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(MeanLatLng)
                                    .title("Property")

                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                            .fromResource(R.drawable.pink_outside_marker))));

        }
    }
```

When I clicked on the particular marker, I need the PropertyID value of that clicked marker,

```
 public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    marker.showInfoWindow();
    tvPropertyID.setText("" + visibleMarkers.get(marker));

    return true;
}
```

but I am getting "visibleMarkers.get(marker)" null. An empty string is displayed on the infowindow. 
   Where I am doing wrong? Please correct me. Please provide me an useful links.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `visibleMarkers.get(marker)` - aren't your keys Strings? Shouldn't it be more like `visibleMarkers.get(PropertyID)`? Assuming PropertyID is a String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"visibleMarkers.get(marker)" is null because your keys are Strings, not Markers.

Here's where you populate the map:

```
visibleMarkers.put(PropertyStub.get(i).PropertyID, ...);
```

Assuming PropertyID is a String, then of course visibleMarkers.get(marker) will be null since you are not getting the right key.

Sounds like you need a `HashMap` of Markers->Strings since you appear to need to lookup the `String` value for a given `Marker`. Change your data structure to `HashMap<Marker,String>` and take it from there.

Comment: This is the way how I instantiated the HashMap : HashMap<String, Marker> visibleMarkers = new HashMap<String, Marker>();

Comment: This is not the data structure you are looking for! Change it to this:  `HashMap<Marker, String> visibleMarkers = new HashMap<Marker, String>();` and of course flip the paramers in your `put` statement.

Comment: Yes! Got the difference. Thanks!!